# Unlock BitLocker drive with batch file generated in C# app

Tags: c#, batch-file, bitlocker

I am working on a C# app that replaces `explorer.exe` with our own shell. We want to let users unlock BitLocker USB drives from within our UI.

The C# app periodically refreshes a list of drives connected to the machine. For each drive found, it checks the BDE status by starting a `Process` that executes `manage-bde -status` and parses the output. It works fine.

**Problem** Unlocking a drive is giving me an issue since

`manage-bde -unlock <drive>: -password`

is an active prompt, and we do not want the user to see Command Prompt open at all to enter text. They will select the drive name and enter the password within the C# app beforehand.

One idea I had was generating a `.bat` file in the C# app using the drive name and password. However I do not know the proper syntax to achieve submitting the password (.bat noob here).

**My (very) WIP batch file**

```
@echo off
set driveName=F:
set pass=thePassword
manage-bde -unlock %driveName% -password
```

How should I proceed to submit the `pass` variable? I understand playing with passwords in plain text is in no way secure, but the most important takeaway I need is knowing how to structure this in a batch file with no user input to cmd.

Thanks.

Comment: Going to try PowerShell cmdlets for make a one-liner. Will check back.

Comment: Why are you using a batch file / cmd.exe, or powershell script / powershell.exe? I'd like to know why you cannot run an executable file with arguments directly from your [tag:C#] code.

Comment: Perhaps I can run an executable from the c# code. This is just the solution I came up with because the commands seemed to do what I need.

Comment: You are running a single program with arguments, there is no need for a script using a lower level language to do that for you.

Comment: You're suggesting I programmatically do BitLocker operations using C#? Do you know of any documentation on that?

Comment: No I'm suggesting that you run `manage-bde.exe` _or `manage-bde.wsf`, depending upon the order of your `%PATHEXT%` value string list_, with arguments from `C#` instead of opening a [tag:batch-file] from `C#`, which in turn will open a [tag:cmd] window, _(or opening a cmd.exe window, and invoking your batch file as an argument to it)_, and within which you launch `manage-bde` passing it two arguments.

Comment: This sort of bring me back to my original issue of not knowing how pass arguments to an active prompt like ```manage-bde -unlock```. A simple example would be beyond helpful.

Comment: Have you tried to pipe it in: `Echo(%pass% | %SystemRoot%\System32\manage-bde.exe -unlock %driveName% -Password`? Or have you considered using a `-RecoveryPassword`, which is your 48-digit recovery key, or retrieve that from a key file instead using the `-RecoveryKey` option? The problem seems to be that you're looking for an answer on how to use a built-in and well documented command, not on how to fix an issue with your code.

Comment: Compo, thank you very much for your comments. I tried piping in the password like you suggested, but got errors. By then I had gotten a PowerShell script doing what I need it to. I'll post it as an answer. Just now I got word we will probably be refactoring everything to make use of Kanguru AES encrypted USB sticks instead... such is life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a PowerShell script solution to work after trying out some suggestions (Thanks Compo). It solves the problem of issuing BitLocker operations without the user interacting with a command prompt. I understand there are more elegant approaches.

```
public void ToggleBDELock(string driveLetter, string password )
        {
            string directory = @"C:\thePath\";
            string scriptName = $"bdeunlock_{driveLetter}.ps1";
            string scriptPath = Path.Combine( directory, scriptName );
            string output;
            FileStream fileStream;

            // Set up location for the script.
            // yada yada yada

            // Write the script to the file. 
            fileStream = File.Create( scriptPath );
            using( var writer = new StreamWriter( fileStream ) )
            {
                writer.WriteLine( $"$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString \"{password}\" -AsPlainText -Force" );
                writer.WriteLine( $"Unlock-BitLocker -MountPoint \"{driveLetter}:\" -Password $SecureString" );
            }

            // Configure a process to run the script.
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "powershell.exe",
                Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file \"{scriptPath}\"",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            // Try to execute the script.
            using( var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo } )
            {
                try
                {
                    process.Start();
                    output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                }
                catch( Exception e )
                {
                    // yada yada yada
                }
            }
        }
```